# Memoization Memory

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

Memoization is definitely a powerful technique.

But Dynamic Programming is slightly better IMO, since it does not involve the memory strain (in a recursive program, the parameters occupy memory and this memory increases as we go deeper into the recursion). But speed-wise, both are pretty equal.

But definitely memoization is a lot more straight-forward than Dynamic Programming.

My question: Is it somehow possible to use memoization without the memory constraint ?

Comment: `(in a recursive program, the parameters occupy memory and this memory increases as we go deeper into the recursion)` This is a constant factor. The recursion cannot possibly go bigger than |Table| (Where Table is the table used in the equivalent DP solution), so it could be worse only by the constant, and in terms of big O - they are the same. In addition, memorization is more useful for sparsed matrix, since you create only 'what you need', unlike bottom-up DP, where you create everything.

Comment: So, the claim that DP is 'slightly better' is basically wrong. Each has its advantages and disadvantages, and each solution (bottom up OR top-down) shine somewhere else.

Comment: Memoization also has the (dis)advantage that the calculated values stay in memory after the calculation. Is that what you meant? Also, I think this question is better suited for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes, but what are the advantages of DP then ?\

Comment: It often happens to me: in online judges, when I use Memoization, I get SIGSEGV, whereas for DP, Accepted. Explanation ? (Same method)

Comment: @hypothesist Each access to memory is much quicker (memorization usually uses a hash-based map, which is O(1) on average but slower than array access). This fact makes bottom-up DP better than top-down for dense data - by a constant, but a high constant, factor.

Comment: @amit So, since I call a function every time, it takes slightly longer time than DP for dense data. But then again, memoization is better when it comes to sparse data, right ?

Comment: @hypothesist (1) as a rule of thumb - yes, there could be exceptions though (none that I can think of at the moment). (2) Note that to my best knowledge they are both called DP, one is bottom-up (what you refer to DP), and the other is top-down (what you refer to as memorization).

Comment: Memoization with recursion is easier to code than equivalent DP. If table is sparsely populated(most of values are not needed) like sometimes in knapsack then memory efficiency of memoization is very good as compared to DP because it uses hash table. So it depends on problem.

Comment: One thing that can be done with DP, but not memoization, is that you can discard temporary results. For example for some particular problems, DP could only need to remember the current and previous rows of an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of DP as a form of memoization which benefits from extremely stringent guarantees on what access patterns occur. Memoization is a "pull" model, where the final answer requests its subparts and those requests lead (indirectly) to the smallest granularity of computation being invoked. DP is a "push" model, where the data that each computation will need is anticipated.

It's possible to reformulate any DP algorithm to use lazy computation and memoization instead of a table, and sometimes even to have the resultant implementation match DP in time and space complexity. however, the second trick generally comes down to keeping the DP implementation in mind and forcing the memoization implementation to "stumble upon" the same access patterns. It's a party trick, not a useful transformation.